# Why is my value of argv[1] changing? (C)

Tags: c, argv

my program takes two command line inputs, `stock.csv` and `coins.csv`. Near the start of my program I have `load_check = load_data(&tm, argv[1], argv[2]);` which initializes the files into linked lists. Problem is, somehow this line of code is changing the value of `argv[1]` to `d`, but `argv[2]` is still `coins.csv`. I'm really confused as to what's causing this, it's really weird. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry about the slow response, found another problem with the code and was fixing it.
Code for `load_data` (now changing `argv[1`] to `""`)

```
BOOLEAN load_data(tm_type * tm, char * stockfile, char * coinsfile)
{
stock_node *sstream = NULL;
char* token;
char line_no[LINE_LENGTH + 1], *ptr;
FILE *sfile, *cfile;
BOOLEAN check = TRUE;
int denom = 0;

if((sfile = fopen(stockfile, "r")) == NULL){

    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s.\n", stockfile);
    check = FALSE;

}

if((cfile = fopen(coinsfile, "r")) == NULL){

    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s.\n", coinsfile);
    check = FALSE;

}

sstream = tm -> stock -> head_stock;

while(fgets(line_no, LINE_LENGTH + 1, sfile) != NULL){

    sstream = malloc(sizeof(tm -> stock));
    sstream -> data = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_data));
    token = strtok(line_no, ",");
    strcpy(sstream -> data -> ticket_name, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    sstream -> data -> ticket_type = token[0];
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(sstream -> data -> ticket_zone, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    sstream -> data -> ticket_price = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    sstream -> data -> stock_level = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    sstream -> next_node = tm -> stock -> head_stock;
    tm -> stock -> head_stock = sstream;

}

while(fgets(line_no, LINE_LENGTH + 1, cfile) != NULL){

    token = strtok(line_no, ",");
    tm -> coins[denom].denomination = strtol(token, &ptr, 01);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    tm -> coins[denom].count = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    denom++;

}

return check;
}
```

The variable change is happening in the fifth iteration of

```
while(fgets(line_no, LINE_LENGTH + 1, cfile) != NULL){

    token = strtok(line_no, ",");
    tm -> coins[denom].denomination = strtol(token, &ptr, 01);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    tm -> coins[denom].count = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
    denom++;

}
```

Also, `tm -> coins[denom].denomination = strtol(token, &ptr, 01);` is giving me a `warning: Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.` error but doesn't seem to be affecting the code any other way.

Definitions: (These were pre-provided startup codes, this is for a class)

```
typedef struct stock_list * stock_list_ptr;
typedef struct coin * coin_list_ptr;
typedef struct tm
{
coin_list_ptr coins;
stock_list_ptr stock;
} tm_type;

struct stock_data 
{
char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
char ticket_type;
char ticket_zone[TICKET_ZONE_LEN+1];
unsigned int ticket_price;
unsigned int stock_level;
};
typedef struct stock_node 
{
struct stock_data * data;
struct stock_node * next_node;
} stock_node;

struct stock_list
{
stock_node * head_stock;
unsigned int num_stock_items;
};
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's actually hard to tell.

Comment: Can't it be debugged?

Comment: The problem is most likely in `load_data` function. Can you post its code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize the `load_data` function would return and update the value of `argv[1]`. Upon stepping through the function it seems to be changing value to `d` in this code block: `if(strtol(token, &ptr, 10) == 5){
            tm -> coins[4].denomination = ONE_DOLLAR;
            token = strtok(line_no, ",");
            tm -> coins[4].count = strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
        }`
but none of these lines reference `argv[1]`.

Comment: @user2860984 Please post it as an update to the question, not as a comment. And post the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for posting the update.  Can you add definitions of `tm_type` and `stock_node` as well please?

Comment: Done. Currently I've just used `strcpy(filename, argv[1]);` at the beginning of the program as a work around, but I'd still like to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change the signature to:

```
BOOLEAN load_data(tm_type * tm, const char * stockfile, const char * coinsfile)
```

This way, you ensure that load_data doesn't modify the data that argv[1] and argv[2] point to.
That won't solve your problem though.

Reg the warning,

```
tm -> coins[denom].denomination = strtol(token, &ptr, 01);
```

is 01 a typo or is denomination an enum with only 2 values?

Also, its important to initialize your pointers and close the file handles.

Comment: We're not allowed to change the start up code that has been assigned to us, the prototypes were all assigned beforehand.

Comment: It is a typo, I missed that.